# r - How does calibration() function calculate Observed Even Percentage

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm trying to work through the example from a book Applied Predictive Modeling (max kuhn). It's an example of created a calibration curve.
I kind of understand the point of that curve, which is to see whether the propotion of actual events is similar to predicted events. But I'm strugling to understand how the Percent column of the output is calculated.
Here is the code:

```
library(AppliedPredictiveModeling)
set.seed(975)
simulatedTrain <- quadBoundaryFunc(500)
simulatedTest <- quadBoundaryFunc(1000)


# Random forest 

library(randomForest)
rfModel <- randomForest(class ~ X1 + X2,
                        data = simulatedTrain,
                        ntree = 2000)


rfTestPred <- predict(rfModel, simulatedTest, type = "prob")

simulatedTest$RFprob <- rfTestPred[,"Class1"]
simulatedTest$RFclass <- predict(rfModel, simulatedTest)

library(caret)

# Calibrating probabilities
calCurve <- calibration(x = class ~ RFprob, data = simulatedTest)
calCurve$data




 calibModelVar            bin  Percent     Lower     Upper Count  midpoint
1         RFprob     [0,0.0909]  4.00000  2.203804  6.620306    14  4.545455
2         RFprob (0.0909,0.182] 20.00000 11.648215 30.832609    15 13.636364
3         RFprob  (0.182,0.273] 33.33333 20.395974 48.410832    16 22.727273
4         RFprob  (0.273,0.364] 37.20930 22.975170 53.274905    16 31.818182
5         RFprob  (0.364,0.455] 35.71429 18.640666 55.934969    10 40.909091
6         RFprob  (0.455,0.545] 53.19149 38.077789 67.888473    25 50.000000
7         RFprob  (0.545,0.636] 65.71429 47.789002 80.867590    23 59.090909
8         RFprob  (0.636,0.727] 72.50000 56.111709 85.399101    29 68.181818
9         RFprob  (0.727,0.818] 83.33333 67.188407 93.627987    30 77.272727
10        RFprob  (0.818,0.909] 95.83333 85.745903 99.491353    46 86.363636
11        RFprob      (0.909,1] 94.00000 90.296922 96.603304   235 95.454545
```

So if we use the first row as an example, what does the `Count = 14` indicate?
As far as I can see, there are 14 rows where RF calculated probability to be between 0-10% (rounding off) and actual class is `Class1`.

```
nrow(simulatedTest[simulatedTest$RFprob >=0 & simulatedTest$RFprob <=0.0909 & simulatedTest$class == "Class1",])
```

When I plot the graph

```
xyplot(calCurve, auto.key = list(columns =2))
```

On the X-axis I understand that it the mid point of the bin which is the `midpoint` column. And that the y-axis is the `Percent` column.
But how is `Percent` column calculated?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `calibration` the calculation of the `Percent` column is made as follows.
First, the predicted probabilities are  splitted into 11 equally spaced intervals.

```
simulatedTest$bin <- cut(simulatedTest$RFprob, 
                         breaks=seq(0,1,length.out=12),
                         include.lowest=T)
table(simulatedTest$bin)

    [0,0.0909] (0.0909,0.182]  (0.182,0.273]  (0.273,0.364]  (0.364,0.455] 
           350             75             48             43             28 
 (0.455,0.545]  (0.545,0.636]  (0.636,0.727]  (0.727,0.818]  (0.818,0.909] 
            47             35             40             36             48 
     (0.909,1] 
           250
```

The column `Count` can be calculated using a simple `table`.

```
(tbl <- table(simulatedTest$bin,simulatedTest$class))

                 Class1 Class2
  [0,0.0909]         14    336
  (0.0909,0.182]     15     60
  (0.182,0.273]      16     32
  (0.273,0.364]      16     27
  (0.364,0.455]      10     18
  (0.455,0.545]      25     22
  (0.545,0.636]      23     12
  (0.636,0.727]      29     11
  (0.727,0.818]      30      6
  (0.818,0.909]      46      2
  (0.909,1]         235     15
```

The `Percent` column contains the row proportions of `tbl`:

```
round(prop.table(tbl,1)*100,2)

                    Class1    Class2
  [0,0.0909]      4.000000 96.000000
  (0.0909,0.182] 20.000000 80.000000
  (0.182,0.273]  33.333333 66.666667
  (0.273,0.364]  37.209302 62.790698
  (0.364,0.455]  35.714286 64.285714
  (0.455,0.545]  53.191489 46.808511
  (0.545,0.636]  65.714286 34.285714
  (0.636,0.727]  72.500000 27.500000
  (0.727,0.818]  83.333333 16.666667
  (0.818,0.909]  95.833333  4.166667
  (0.909,1]      94.000000  6.000000
```

`calibration` calculates confidence intervals for these proportions using `binom.test`:

```
t(apply(tbl, 1, function(x) { 
   bintst <- binom.test(x=x[1], n=sum(x))  
   round(100*c(bintst$estimate,bintst$conf.int),6)
   }))

                 probability of success                    
  [0,0.0909]                    4.00000  2.203804  6.620306
  (0.0909,0.182]               20.00000 11.648215 30.832609
  (0.182,0.273]                33.33333 20.395974 48.410832
  (0.273,0.364]                37.20930 22.975170 53.274905
  (0.364,0.455]                35.71429 18.640666 55.934969
  (0.455,0.545]                53.19149 38.077789 67.888473
  (0.545,0.636]                65.71429 47.789002 80.867590
  (0.636,0.727]                72.50000 56.111709 85.399101
  (0.727,0.818]                83.33333 67.188407 93.627987
  (0.818,0.909]                95.83333 85.745903 99.491353
  (0.909,1]                    94.00000 90.296922 96.603304
```

In `calibration` all these calculations are performed by the `caret:::calibCalc` function. 
I hope it could help you.